# Choosing which WAN IP to use from proxy server

Tags: server, proxy, http-proxy, windows-server

Sorry for the stupid question, I know it's stupid since I understand the concept, but I have been trying to configure Squid server and CCProxy without much success.

I have a NIC with 2 static private IPs and 2 public static IPs.

They are let's say 10.0.1.4 with primary static Public IP, and secondary 10.0.1.5 with static Public IP.

I want to connect from a home network to the proxy server using at least one of it's public IPs and when I get authenticated to be able to choose which public IP to use.

Let's say if I use port 3128 it will use the 10.0.1.4 network with the primary public IP.
If I want to use port 3129 it will use the 10.0.1.5 network with the secondary public IP.

I properly setup the network on my windows server by adding the secondary private IP in Ethernet interface on the NIC.

I have configured Squid to acknowledge the 2 private IPs and CONNECT/HTTP traffic from my public IP at home.

I opened the ports 3128 and 3129 and connected to them. I added an inbound rule to firewall. It works, I can use the primary public IP and 3128 to connect, or the secondary public IP and 3129 to connect.

The issue is on IP check it shows the main IP address. No matter to which interface I connect for the proxy.

How can I configure it so it uses a specific WAN when authenticated to the proxy server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

create an outgoing TCP connection for each inbound one through a port.